# Is it acceptable to use two "до этого"s with two different meanings like this?

Tags: словоупотребление

In conversation, I just said:

> Именно. Так мы сможем получить столько средств, сколько нам хватит. Никто еще не **додумался до этого**. Это же гениально!

Leaving aside the question of  stylistic awkwardness, if I want to replace "еще" with "до этого" in the sense of "раньше", can I say:

> Никто **до этого** не додумался **до этого**. (=== Никто **до этого** не додумался **раньше**.)

The "до этого" placed at the end of the sentence in my original phrasing is related to "додуматься", whereas in the paraphrased version, the "до этого" at the end -- despite taking the same position -- is meant as "раньше".

Answer (score 5):

You can't because **до этого** must refer to a point in the past. In other words, you can only use it to say "no-one *had* thought of this before", not "no-one *has* thought of this before". If it was part of a story you were narrating, though, you could, if only as a kind of formalist whimsy.

> Никто **до этого** не додумался **до этого**. (=== Никто **до этого** не додумался **раньше**.)

Actually, it's the first **до этого** that parses as "before"; I can't quite put my finger on why, but it's very unusual for the "before" **до этого** to go to the end of the sentence — much like you wouldn't end a sentence with **еще** unless you wanted it to mean "more".

Answer (score 3):

No, avoid this ambiguous reduplication here.

Better say

> Никто до сих пор не додумался до этого.

Or, if you want to mention a person

> Никто до него/них (ещё) не додумался до этого.

Answer (score 2):

Having two "до этого" in one sentence is not advised, because one of them will mean a point in time, while the other - an object of discussion.

While this still allows the sentence to be understood, which one of the two "до этого" will mean a point in time will depend on the reader almost entirely, as that sentence structure has no guides either way, which is why going this route is not advised - this would just be confusing to the reader, slowing down their comprehension.

As a rule of thumb, I try always to not have any duplicating words precisely because of this.